# Nexus 7: Compass drifts over time

Tags: nexus-7, orientation, calibration, compass

When I use apps like Google Maps on my Nexus 7, I find that the compass drifts, with the indicated direction rotating counterclockwise over time (from north to west to south to east).  As a result, I am unable to rely on the direction information.

Is this a hardware issue?  Is there something I can do to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the compass needed to be calibrated.  I rotated the tablet a full 360 degrees in all three axes, and the problem cleared up.

I used [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Test_Sensors&hl=en) to monitor the orientation sensor, and while I still see the X axis orientation value drifting, it is being corrected automatically so that accuracy is maintained.